# Why doesn't PrintWriter.println() terminate lines when writing to HTML?

Tags: java, servlets, line-breaks, printwriter

If I use method `println()` for writing to a **file** or **console**, it writes a message and terminates. Easy enough. But now I want it to write to *HTML* page using *Servlet* class. Code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            pw.println("hello " + i);
        }
}
```

What I was expected is to get message printed in each line (as if I used `<br>`), like this:

```
hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
...
```

But this is what I got:
[image]

Can someone tell me why isn't every message printed in new line? While if I had used this same code for writing to a *file* or *system.out*, it would get desired output. Meaning why I need to put `<br>` for this code to work that way, even thought I am using `println()` which should implicitly do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the HTML, you'll see newlines in there. But when rendered in a browser, the browser ignores whitespace and converts it to a single space. See this snippet:

```html
<body>
<div>
Hey
Jude
don't
be
afraid
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Then shouldn't I get my messages in single line and have to scroll left and right to see it all? Notice how it renders it perfectly to fit into width. How did it do that?

Comment: re *How did it do that?*  Because that's what browsers generally do --- fill text to fit available space.  Try resizing the browser in which you're reading this/

Comment: Because in html text, whitespace is not significant.

Comment: If you want the browser to render new lines for each output you must output `<br/>` tags after each line.  `<br>` is what the browser knows means "break to the next line"